# Possible to use HTTP request to probe MIME configured in Apache settings?

Tags: apache, httprequest, mime

This question is a bit weird. Given that I do not have access to the Apache server, I want to check if an Apache web server is using proper MIME type to handle specific file format, such as `image/jpeg` for `.jpg` files.

As MIME is shown in HTTP response, for example:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
cache-control:private, max-age=31536000
content-length:16786
content-type:image/jpeg <---
date:Mon, 21 Aug 2017 09:56:08 GMT
expires:Mon, 21 Aug 2017 09:56:08 GMT
last-modified:Wed, 14 Dec 2016 20:30:00 GMT
server:sffe
status:200
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

If a web server is configured incorrectly, for example adding:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .jpg
```

in `.htaccess` or in Apache configuration file, I would like to use HTTP request to diagnose. Is it possible? Will the Apache server responded with `application/x-httpd-php` when I'm requesting a `.jpg` from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `curl -I http://yoursite.com/test.jpg` which will give you the content-type in return along with other info.

Comment: Nice one. Even better, `curl -sI http://yoursite.com/test.jpg | grep "Content-Type"` to output only the Content-Type line.